# Give me a suggestion to improve my app performance, on retrieving huge data(nearly more than 10,000 records) from server?

Tags: android

On performance view, JSON parsing take huge time for retrieving Data.In my app i need to get nearly 10,000 records from Server.On emulator,it gets data immediately and works efficiently.But in my android phone,it takes more than 2 minutes to retrieve all data.Kindly,give me a suggestion for improve the performance on phone.

Comment: It seems you're doing file/network/parsing operation in UI/Main Thread. Don't do that. It will take a minute and the UI is freezing.

Comment: If internet(CDMA or LTE or Wifi...etc) is low, it's very difficult. using ASinktask or Thread and viewing progressbar.

Comment: I tried with AsyncTask.I created views dynamically.On publishing data to UI,it started problems.

Comment: Are you using WCF and OData service to send and receive information ?

Comment: using Odata service,not exactly doing.I interacting with dot-net server

Answer (score 1):

The emulator has access to your host machine's resources and is therefore not a good way to test performance.

I have used the [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) streaming JSON parser with large data sets and it works well for me. However, I run this process in the background and am able to accept long fetch/parse times. Depending on the size of the data and the speed of the device you're running on, 2 minutes does not seem extraordinarily long to me.

Maybe you could fetch a smaller subset of the data first, and then display it while you fetch the rest in the background. You're probably going to have to do some kind of optimization like this in order to improve performance.

Comment: i will try to do like tht.. and replying you after

Comment: The emulator runs a jvm on an emulated arm cpu. I don't think it were faster as a real android device in most configurations.

Comment: @PeterHorvath, that depends on what options you've selected for your AVD. If it's configured to use an Intel-based image, it runs very fast. In this case, it sounds like the emulator is quite a bit faster than the device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can parse the complex JSON response using GSON. Please check these tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

You just create the model classes and use the proper annotations then the data will be parsed to model objects directly.

Comment: I already using model classes with annotations,here problem is on JSON parsing for retrieving huge data.

Comment: Why were the parsing with gson faster?

Comment: @PeterHorvath : From a usability point of view, take a look at the benchmark test code and compare the code required for Gson versus the code required for Jackson:

Gson:
https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/blob/0e353b5e90799b328f21664b730598dfd9618beb/tpc/src/serializers/Gson.java

Jackson:
https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/blob/0e353b5e90799b328f21664b730598dfd9618beb/tpc/src/serializers/JsonJacksonManual.java

The Gson team is committed to increase performance with each release
and I am now much happy with the results in the last two releases
(2.2.3 and 2.2.4).

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what causes this slowdown. Because of everything goes in the rmulator like charm, it is probably the network speed. You can help this if you find a solution to compress the json data.

It is a text, with a lot of repeat, it is very, very good compressable. And http supports compression.

You need to set it in your http server.

If you find this a promising direction, I suggest to make a new question, giving your http server version. Good luck!